# How can I search a text using regex excluding a character?

Tags: regex, vim

I want to search a text using regex using \S but excluding the "," at the end.

p.e.:
text, tàta réta

My regex must find text (without the ",") tàta réta

I tried this but it didn't work:

/\<\S+[^,]

\w doesn't work also, because it doesn't find the non ascii characters èéòà etc.

Comment: Please clarify, what do you want to find? Can you add an example of what you DON'T want to be matched?

Comment: @Andrea, I want to match \S except the ",".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read up on

```
:he /zero-width
```

I think with default options you meant (note the `\+` instead of just `+`)

```
/\<\S\+[^,]
```

This won't work because + is greedy by default, and the comma is not a whitespace :)

I suppose this would do what you want:

```
/\<\S\{-}\>,\@!
```

With verymagic, this could be a whole lot cleaner

```
/\v<\S+>,@!
```

Comment: thank you for answering. I checked both. The first one doesn't find "text",  the 2nd one (the verymagic one) find "text," with the ","

Comment: Sorry, missed a spot, updating

Comment: Found it with your help: /\\(\S\+\\),\@<! - tnx

Comment: It works but I'm still trying to understand why above code works. Can anyone help me to explain what it does?